# Is it proper to mark a param as @Nullable and then throw an IllegalArgumentException when a null is passed in?

Tags: java, nullable

So I just drilled into my colleague that he should not be doing as the title states. But I fought so strongly for my stance that I want to make sure that I am actually right (the worst thing I want to do is enforce an incorrect opinion on someone else).

So basically I'm trying to verify that the following is indeed bad practice:

```
public void methodA(@Nullable String value) {
  if (value == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  ...
}
```

His argument was that `@Nullable` simply states that you can pass a `null` in here, but it doesn't guarantee that the result of doing so will be "nice".

Whereas my argument is that doing so breaks the contract that `@Nullable` implies that a `null` value will be properly handled and not treated as *exceptional*.

The problem is I can't find any documentation actually verifying my claim.

Ultimately I was able to convince him of my stance, but now I'm concerned that perhaps I was wrong.

---

Ah, I am missing some context here. So we are using `@NonNullApi` from Spring, which by default puts a `@Nonnull` on all the params. So if you want to support a null param, you need to override this with a `@Nullable` annotation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Checker Framework manual, [section "Annotations indicate non-exceptional behavior"](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#annotate-normal-behavior), supports your point of view.  It states:

> You should use annotations to specify *normal* behavior. The annotations indicate all the values that you want to flow to a reference — not every value that might possibly flow there if your program has a bug.

Under your colleague's reasoning:

> His argument was that `@Nullable` simply states that you can pass a `null` in here, but it doesn't guarantee that the result of doing so will be "nice".

every reference type could be annotated as `@Nullable`, and thus `@Nullable` would have no meaning.

Comment: Great argument and appreciate the link!

Answer (score 4):

> The problem is I can't find any documentation actually verifying my claim.

Here's some documentation from the [JetBrains Annotations](https://github.com/JetBrains/java-annotations) library:

[`Nullable`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jetbrains/annotations/20.1.0/org/jetbrains/annotations/Nullable.html):

> An element annotated with `Nullable` claims `null` value is perfectly valid to return (for methods), pass to (parameters) or hold in (local variables and fields).

[`NotNull`](https://javadoc.io/static/org.jetbrains/annotations/20.1.0/org/jetbrains/annotations/NotNull.html):

> An element annotated with `NotNull` claims `null` value is forbidden to return (for methods), pass to (parameters) and hold (local variables and fields).

I would say a contract such as "I will definitely throw an exception if you pass a null to this parameter!" would make null a "forbidden" value to pass to that parameter. You should use `@NotNull` (or similar) to annotate it instead. It's certainly not a "perfectly valid" value to pass to that parameter.

Of course, your colleague could still argue that since passing `null` *compiles*, it's "perfectly valid" :) but that's just sophistry IMO.

---

I understand that you are using Spring's annotations, but the wordings in Spring's documentation isn't as strong as the JetBrains' ones, which is why I chose the latter to make a stronger argument. Hopefully you would agree that both pairs of annotations are designed to solve the same problems, and have the same semantics. It would be absurd to have a situation where you should mark something as `org.springframework.lang.Nonnull`, but not `org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't disagree with anything you say (obviously, since we hold the same stance). But it's good to hear that someone else has the same line of reasoning as I do.